What did Miles’s associate steal from Alchemax?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Peter Parker discovers that the override key, which is used to
destroy the super-collider, is broken:

Miles Morales: Can't we make another one?
Peter Parker: We can't do anything. Thanks to you, I have to re-steal
what your guy stole from Alchemax...and make another one of these.

What did Miles’s associate steal from Alchemax?

"your guy" is referring to the Spider-Man/Peter Parker in Miles' universe, and not an associate of Miles.
The Peter Parker (from another universe) talking to Miles is saying he needs to steal another override key because the one originally stolen is now broken beyond repair.
